# Как отправить запрос методом POST на адрес ROOT URL?

Tags: php, json, post

Как отправить POST запрос следующего вида:

```
POST /gate/ki-site-api/ HTTP/1.1
Host: api.site.ru
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

id=get_pdf&username=username&params=...
```

Пробую сделать так:

```
<?
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$url = 'https://api.site.ru/gate/sie-api/';
$data = array('id' => 'make_pdf', 'username' => 'username','account_id' =>'1152289', 'period_id' => '201705');

$params = array(
    'http' => array(

        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($params);
$result = file_get_contents($url, true, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) 

var_dump($result);

?>
```

Получаю ответ:

> HTML> string(51) "{"err_msg": "Authorization failed.", "err_code": 1}"

Из документации:

> Для того, чтобы обратиться к конкретному методу API, Вам необходимо отправить запрос методом POST на адрес ROOT URL. Этот запрос должен содержать следующие обязательные параметры:
>
> id - идентификатор метода, который Вы намерены вызвать. Например, get_main_id. См. раздел соответствующей группы методов.
>
> username - ваше имя пользователя - username.

Не могу понять как пройти авторизацию и получить нужные данные.
$url и username в описании изменены. Может ли не проходить авторизация из-за того что я выполняю запрос со стороннего сайта?

Comment: file_get_contents не подойдет. Пользуйтесь curl

Comment: @Vfvtnjd и по какой же причине не подойдет?

Comment: @Vfvtnjd С чего вы это взяли? В данном случае подойдет, если конечно правильно настроить опции контекста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что разработчик API не указал, что запросы можно отправлять с доменов которым был дан доступ.

Скрипт рабочий. Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку API находится на HTTPS, то помимо HTTP, вам еще нужно настроить [SSL-опции](https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php), добавив в массив опций соотв-щий подмассив с ключом `ssl`.
Если у вас на сервере есть файл сертификата, то нужно указать путь к нему опцией `cafile` либо `capath`. Если же его у вас нет, то вам нужно отключить опции `verify_peer` и `verify_peer_name`.

Кроме того, вы передаете неправильный URL API. В описании запроса у вас указан URL `'https://gate/ki-site-api/'`, а в `file_get_contents` по факту передается `'https://api.site.ru/gate/sie-api/'`.

В итоге ваш код должен примерно таким:

```
$url = 'https://api.site.ru/gate/ki-site-api/';
$data = array('id' => 'make_pdf', 'username' => 'username','account_id' =>'1152289', 'period_id' => '201705');

$params = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    ),
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($params);
$result = file_get_contents($url, true, $context);
```